# redux-saga: function is called twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, generator, redux-saga

I am toggling visibility of a modal in react based on result of some logic performed in saga middleware by dispatching action from saga.

I went through:

- [Action is being dispatched twice](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/527) on github
- [takeEvery/takeLatest is executed twice even though action dispatched only once](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/1345)

  - Wasn't very helpful.

**Store**

```
export default function configureStore(preloadedState) {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
  const middlewares = [..otherMiddleware, sagaMiddleware, ...someMoreMiddlewares];

  const store = createStore({
    // other configuration,
    // middleWares
  })

  sagaMiddleware.run(rootRunner);
  return store;
}
```

**Reducer**:

```
const initialState = {
  activeSwitch: '1',
  modalVisibility: false,
}

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'TOGGLE_MODAL':
      return state.set('modalVisibility', !state.get('modalVisibility'));
    case 'UPDATE_ACTIVE_SWITCH':
      // update active switch
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Action**:

```
export const switchOption = payload => ({
  type: 'SWITCH_OPTION',
  payload,
})

export const toggleModal = () => ({
  type: 'TOGGLE_MODAL',
})

export const updateActiveSwitch = payload => ({
  type: 'UPDATE_ACTIVE_SWITCH',
  payload,
})
```

**Component**:

```
import switchOption from 'action';

function Component(props) {
  return <div onClick={props.switchOpt(somePayloadParameter)} />;
}

const mapDispatchToProps = state => ({
  switchOpt: (somePayloadParameter) => dispatch(switchOption(somePayloadParameter)),
})

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Component);
```

**RootSaga**:

```
export default function* rootRunner() {
  yield all([ fork(watcher) ])
}
```

**Saga**:

```
function* worker(payload) {
  console.log('hey');
  yield put({'TOGGLE_MODAL'})
  // Perform some task and wait for modal ok button click
  yield take('MODAL_OK');
  if (taskSuccess) {
  yield put({ type: 'UPDATE_ACTIVE_SWITCH', someValue});
  yield put({ type: 'TOGGLE_MODAL'}};
}

export default function* watcher() {
  while(true) {
    yield actionObj = yield take('SWITCH_OPTION');
    yield call(worker, actionObj.payload);
  }
}
```

Modal is never visible as 'TOGGLE_MODAL' is being dispatched twice from saga, as a result of `watcher` calling `worker` twice.

If I put a `debugger` just after `while(true) {` in `watcher`, **on page load**, that breakpoint is hit twice.

Even if I remove every line from `worker`, it is still running twice.

Why is my saga code running twice?

---

**EDIT**

**Component**:

```
import switchOption from 'action';

function Component(props) {
  return <div onClick={props.switchOpt(somePayloadParameter)} />;
}

const mapDispatchToProps = state => ({
  // switchOption is action from action.js
  switchOpt: (somePayloadParameter) => dispatch(switchOption(somePayloadParameter)),
})

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Component);
```

**Redux monitor middleware** logs to the console in dev tools following three actions, after executing saga function when it is called `onClick` for the first time:

- 'SWITCH_OPTION'
- 'TOGGLE_MODAL' --> with `modalVisibility` set to `true`
- 'TOGGLE_MODAL' --> with `modalVisibility` set to `false`

Now the click on `div` becomes useless as MODAL never popped up and there is no *OK* button to click on.

Comment: Maybe if you add more complete code we can see where the flow is going. As a loose try fore example, I guess in you reducer you have always a "return" statement for each case, otherwise UPDATE_ACTIVE_SWITCH will be executed twice, first when opening the popup and a second time when really updating the switch.

Comment: @CarlosRuana, I updated the code so that its more complete, I can't seem to identify the bug neither could find a way to debug sagas. Now I am reading examples in https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/tree/master/examples

Comment: In the component you have "switchOption: () => dispatch(toggleVisibility())" but I do not see that implementation of toggleVisibility on actions and the relation then to the toggleModal or the reducer. Is there something still missing in that code that you can attach?

Comment: @CarlosRuana Please look at **Edit** part of the question. I have updated the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Right now `Component` is calling `props.switchOpt` every time it renders. Instead, create a new function that can be passed by reference and is then called with `onClick`:

```
function Component(props) {
  return <div onClick={() => { props.switchOpt(somePayloadParameter); }} />;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, `switchOption` is the action that I am importing from `action.js`, whereas `switchOpt` is a `prop` of `Component`. I have edited the question. In `mapDispatchToProps`, I think I am passing a reference. `switchOpt` [see **EDIT**] is suppose to run `onClick` only. How is it effected every time component renders?

Comment: I see. The issue is the same, but the solution is different. I updated my answer.

Comment: That didn't solve the issue, saga function is still called twice, as a result, `TOGGLE_MODAL` action gets dispatched two time. Then, `SWITCH_OPTION` just waits on `take('MODAL_OK')` but the modal never popped up.

Comment: I think the first think you should do is apply @RossAllen fix as the breakpoint was stopping  in yield take('SWITCH_OPTION') twice because you were executing the function on every render. Can you provide more info about which is the new flow after the fix? Maybe you can also add a breakpoint on the render.